# How to make sound persist when Power Point file is used in different media

Tags: libreoffice, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I want to import audio from some location into a PowerPoint file (which I edit with LibreOffice 6.4.2) and then copy it to a CD and present the PowerPoint file.

However, when I copy the file to the CD and use it on a different Linux or Microsoft computer, it does not play the audio, as the audio link is not on these computers.

Is there a way of adding audio to a presentation and having it follow when the presentation is saved and burnt to a CD, i.e. making it a permanent part of the presentation no matter what computer one uses the file on?

Answer (score 2):

*Libreoffice Impress* uses **relative location**, so copy the audio files into the folder where **Power Point file is located**, import them **from new location** into *Impress* and then burn the folder contents into CD. Now the audio files will play.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft PowerPoint saves presentations in .ppt or .pptx format. The default file format in PowerPoint version 2007 or newer is .pptx. There are also two additional PowerPoint AutoPlay formats, .pps and .ppsx.

LibreOffice Impress which is the default presentation application in Ubuntu saves files in .odp format by default. Google Slides in Google Drive can convert .ppt/.pps/.pptx/.ppsx presentations to .odp.

1. Upload a copy of your presentation to Google Drive.
2. Right-click the presentation and select *Open in Google Slides*.
3. In Google Slide select *File* -> *Download* -> *ODP Document (.odp)*.
4. Open the downloaded .odp presentation in the built-in Impress application.